# Running an external script from Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, r, ms-access-2007

I want my Access application to run an external program (in this case a R script) after the user clicks a button. I use this code:

```
Dim RetVal
RetVal = Shell("""C:\Program Files\R\R-2.10.1\bin\R.exe"" CMD BATCH --no-environ --silent --no-restore --no-save ""c:\test.R"" ""c:\test-result.txt""", vbHide)
MsgBox RetVal
```

This works fine, but the VBA code keeps on running while my script is executed. How can I make Access waiting for the script to be finished? Has anybody suggestions about how to give an error message of the script back to Access?

Comment: May be of interest: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1152885

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit reluctant about using low-level kernel32 code, but maybe I should give it a try. And what about giving back a message from the external program/script to the calling Access code?

Comment: I meant PHVs suggestion where wit on return is set to true: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Perhaps you can redirect the output to file that can be read? http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Thanks again. And yes, redirect to a file and read that file will be the best (only?) way. I was wondering if there's a API like way. So.

Comment: Why would you have any reluctance to use Windows APIs? You do realize that the VBA Shell() command is just a wrapper around some Windows APIs, right?

Comment: Yes, but the wrapper is a black-box made by Microsoft, so I don't have to worry if it's implemented correctly (...). But you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenProcess and WaitForSingleObject combo that @Remou links to, is probably your best bet for doing this.  You should take a look at [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx), it's a nice drop in module for shell and wait.

For returning a message back from the script, you could mess around with [redirecting the scripts input and output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx).  This is not for the faint of heart.  As an alternative I would [redirect the output of the script to a text file](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true), then read in that file after it exits.

Comment: @Remou meant the second option, the CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run code. That's just 1 sentence of code, the Shell And Wait code at cpearson.com around 250 sentences. I'm not lazy, but ... ;-)

Comment: >Mark: Thanks, I'll consider the different options

Comment: I was trying to run the code @ http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx. But I think it's VBA written especially for Excel. I'm using Access VBA and it's starts complaining about XlEnableCancelKey ('Type not defined')

Comment: @waanders, good point, I should have read a little more carefully, you are correct there is A LOT of excel specific constants in there.  Here's a "dumbed" down version without all the bells and whistles (and the Excel stuff):  http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0004.htm

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this ShellWait routine doesn't return a value indicating if the process completed successfully. I've to change it a bit